# C# Struct method doesn't save value if accessed by a property

Tags: c#, .net, struct, properties

I need to create a structure that looks like an int (but has an extra field that I need...), so I created a new structure named TestStruct added one method (test()) that I needed and overloaded some operators, and it seemed to be working well...

The sample below shows the problem. If the structure test() method is executed from the Val property then the Val property seems to lose the value, but if the method is executed on the Val2 variable, this one seems to keep the right value...

Why does this happen?

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new TestClass();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestStruct Val { get; set; }
    private TestStruct Val2;

    public TestClass()
    {
        Val.test();
        Console.WriteLine(Val + "-> why is it not 10?");

        //Direct assignment works well...
        Val = 123;
        Console.WriteLine(Val  + "-> direct assingment works..");

        //This way works too. Why doesn't it work with "get;" and "set;"?
        Val2.test();
        Console.WriteLine(Val2 + "-> it works this way");
    }
}

public struct TestStruct
{
    private Int32 _Value;
    public long Offset { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator TestStruct(Int32 value)
    {
        return new TestStruct { _Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator Int32(TestStruct value)
    {
        return value._Value;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        _Value = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: A mutable struct, these be dark times.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: What's evil is not mutable value types, but the way compilers seem to assume that copies may be used interchangeably with the originals. The paradigm of storing information in value types that are passed by reference is in many regards vastly superior to the paradigm of using promiscuous reference types for everything. If class 'foo' has a mutable structure 'bar', that structure can be passed by reference to other functions in such a way that they can modify bar while they're in scope, but once they return 'bar' will be safe from outside modification. If 'bar' were a class...

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: ...any outside code which ever got a reference to it would be able to modify it using that reference forevermore.  While it would be possible pass a wrapper object instead of the real one, and invalidate the wrapper after the called function returned, that's much ickier than simply passing a value type by reference, which would be the right paradigm if .Net languages didn't have some holes in their value type support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `struct` is wrong.

For a very large number of reasons, you should **never** make a mutable struct.

Just like an `int` or `DateTime` value is immutable and can never change, so too a specific value of your `struct` must never change at all.

Instead, you can make functions that return a new, different value .

Here are some reasons that mutable structs are evil:

1. http://ericlippert.com/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/
2. http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/when-shouldnt-you-write-ref-this.html
3. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you/
4. http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-i-discovered-a-bug-in-the-c-compiler-part-1/

---

To answer the question, `Val.test()` is equivalent to `get_Val().test()`.
Since structs are value types, `get_Val() (the automatically-generated property getter) returns a **copy** of the struct.
The original struct in the private backing field is not affected.

Comment: Thanks, those links helped me out understanding how it works, now it makes sense ;)

Comment: @EricLippert: What other kind of type represents a group of independent but related variables which one wants to be able to work with individually or collectively, but which should not have an identity?  An exposed-field struct *is* a group of independent variables which can be worked with individually or collectively but should have no identity apart from its storage location.  I've seen 20 zillion people saying "mutable structs are evil", but immutable types are cumbersome and it's hard to avoid mutable class types acquiring unwanted identities.  What other types exist?

Comment: @supercat: That's a very abstract question. Can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: @EricLippert: Sure.  Consider the lowly rectangle.  If a rectangle is stored as an exposed-field structure, code which only needs to resize it or move its origin point can do so without having to rewrite the whole thing, and member accesses to a rectangle--even one declared `readonly`, can avoid copying the whole thing to a temporary variable.  If it's stored as an immutable class, changes become much less efficient.  If it's stored as a mutable class, any code that wants to receive or expose a rectangle's location must copy the coordinates to a new instance.

Comment: @EricLippert: I would posit that what makes a "Rectangle" a good usage case for an exposed-field struct is not that it's used in "high-performance code", but rather that a storage location of that type represents a set of four numbers whose values can be chosen independently, but which can only be changed by writing that storage location.  If `Rectangle`'s members are properties it won't be clear whether `Height` can be negative, or whether `Y+Height` is guaranteed not to overflow.  If they're simply `int` fields, it will be clear that code which accepts a `Rectangle` should...

Comment: ...assume nothing about its members that it wouldn't assume if it accepted independent `X`, `Y`, `Width`, and `Height` parameters.

Comment: @supercat: I see the *benefit* of such a scheme but that also comes with costs. It is very easy for even normally careful programmers to extract code that does a mutation of `rect.x` to another method, and forget that the rectangle has to be passed `ref` to preserve the mutation. C# was designed to occupy a reasonable middle ground between the sort of flexibility you want and the sort of automatic accident prevention I want. Mutable value types just happen to occupy an awkward spot on that middle ground.

Comment: @EricLippert: What would you think of the idea of defining an attribute which to tag which struct members should or should not usable on read-only struct values?  That should be relatively cheap to implement, and would seem to avoid many of the "accident" cases while excluding none of the useful ones.  On a related note, allow properties to indicate whether they should or should not allow implicit read-modify-write sequences, and allow `ref` parameters to indicate whether they should accept such properties [so that `MyListOfPoints[i].X=4;` could generate code with the temp, as could...

Comment: @supercat: It sounds like you're asking for C++-style `const`-correctness.

Comment: ...`MyListOfPoints[i].Offset(3,4);` or `TypicalMethod(ref MyListOfPoints[i]);`, but `Interlocked.Increment(ref MyListOfPoints[i]);` would be forbidden.  I'm not asking for enforceable `const` correctness--merely a means for methods to say whether the implicit transform with a temp should be allowed or forbidden.  If a struct method claims not to modify the underlying struct, but it modifies it anyway, the compiler would compile broken code just as it does now.

Comment: @supercat: If by "attribute" you mean the `[Blah]` syntax: generally speaking the compiler team seeks to avoid attributes that modify the meaning of code. That is, attributes that appear *in source code*. Obviously compiler-generated attributes are used all the time to modify the meaning of code in metadata. If you mean more generally the notion of a modifier like `public` or `readonly` then sure, that seems like a reasonable feature, to be evaluated against all the other reasonable features on the list.

Comment: Rather than try to have languages designers try to craft perfect universally-applicable rules for when various implicit transforms should be allowed, I'd much rather see them provide means by which programmers can indicate when transforms should be allowed or forbidden.  Given `double d; float f;`, the expression `f.Equals(d)`; is legal but almost certainly wrong; such mistakes could generate diagnostics, with very few false positives, if `Equals(Object)` could tag its parameter with an attribute "Do not consider boxing conversions if any other overload exists."

Comment: @EricLippert: I understand a desire to avoid having code with an attribute compile one way and code without compile another.  On the other hand, if the guy who writes a method--whether in C# or any other language--knows that any attempt to use it on a read-only struct instance will generate bogus code and marks it with a `[RequireMutable(true)]` attribute, I don't see any harm in having the compiler squawk if one tries to use it on a read-only instance.  C# could if desired specify its own syntax in addition, but...

Comment: ...the definition of the attribute would have to be the starting point to allow the compiler to know how it should behave when calling outside code.

Answer (score 8):

It's a struct, so it's a value type - it's copied by value, not by reference.

Properties are just syntactic sugar around method calls, Val compiles down to this:

```
private TestStruct _valBackingField;
public TestStruct get_Val {
    return _valBackingField;
}
```

When accessing a struct through a property, you are getting a fresh copy every time you access the Getter. When accessing a struct through a field, you are getting the same object every time.

That's why mutable value types are considered evil™.

Comment: Now I see why ppl usually stay away from this
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use Val, the property is returning a copy , it's that copy you modify, then you access the property again which gets another copy.

If you change the struct to a class this problem should go away because if the difference in how classes and structs are treated.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some links, I understand the problem..

I've fix it by changing the `test()` method to return a new structure with the new value and then instead of doing `Val.test()` I do `Val = Val.test();`.

I think a similar situation occurs when we want to replace some chars in a string, we must do something like `str = str.replace("xx","yy");`

Thank you all for helping me out. I didn't expect to get all those replies so quickly