# struct in C# doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, struct

I'm working on a simple application and I'm a little confused. I have a simple `struct Point` with `int x` and `int y`. And I use it for `Line`

```
public class Line : Shape {

    public Line() {
        PointA = new Point(x: 0, y: 0);
        PointB = new Point(x: 0, y: 0);
    }

    public Point PointA { get; set; }
    public Point PointB { get; set; }
}
```

and somewhere

```
var line = new Line();
line.PointB = new Point(x: 4, y: 2);
Console.WriteLine($"Line start at {line.PointA.GetX()}:{line.PointA.GetY()}; end at {line.PointB.GetX()}:{line.PointB.GetY()}");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    line.PointB.IncrementX();
    line.PointB.IncrementY();
}
Console.WriteLine($"Line start at {line.PointA.GetX()}:{line.PointA.GetY()}; end at {line.PointB.GetX()}:{line.PointB.GetY()}");
```

Here need to increment `x` and `y` of `Point` but result doesn't change:

> Line start at 0:0; end at 4:2
>   Line start at 0:0; end at 4:2

What I'm doing wrong? It seems strange. Are there some specific rules to use `struct` in C#. I know that this is a value type but I think it is a good for Point. All examples uses `struct` for Point. Please help?

Point:

```
public struct Point {

    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    : this() {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public void IncrementX() {
        _x++;
    }
    public void IncrementY() {
        _y++;
    }

    public int GetX() {
        return _x;
    }
    public int GetY() {
        return _y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the point class look like?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Updated, please see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Struct method doesn't save value if accessed by a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770604/c-sharp-struct-method-doesnt-save-value-if-accessed-by-a-property)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struct is a value type. And it is passed by value (i.e. by creating copy of all fields) instead of passing reference to struct instance. So when you do

```
line.PointB.IncrementX()
```

When you call getter of PropertyB, it returns **copy** of Point which is stored at PropertyB backing field. And then you call increment on **copy**. Thus original value will stay unchanged.

Further reading: [Value and Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx) and especially [Mutating Readonly Structs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/) which says

> mutable value types are evil. Try to always make value types
>   immutable.

---

What you can do if you want to actually move line point?

- Change Point type to `class`. Then it will be passed by reference, and all methods will be called on original point which you store in `Line`.
- Assign new (modified) point instance to line

I.e. you should store copy, change it and assign back

```
var point = line.PointB; // get copy
point.IncrementX();      // mutate copy
point.IncrementY();
line.PointB = point;     // assign copy of copy
```

You can also make your Point struct immutable (the best thing you can do for value types):

```
public struct Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Point IncrementX() => new Point(X + 1, Y);
    public Point IncrementY() => new Point(X, Y + 1);
    public Point Move(int dx, int dy) => new Point(X + dx, Y + dy);
}
```

And now changing location will look like

```
line.PointB = line.PointB.Move(1, 1);
```

Comment: Could you please a little bit explain what I should do in my case, thanks